# google map satellite view with labels using leaflet labels are not visible

Tags: leaflet

I am using leaflet framework and showing google map satellite view , I want the labels on the satellite view they are not showing up. I used code below

```js
var styled = L.gridLayer.googleMutant({
 type: 'satellite',
 styles: [
  {elementType: 'labels', stylers: [{visibility: 'on'}]},
  {featureType: 'water', stylers: [{color: 'white'}]}
 ]
}).addTo(map);
```

Comment: Then you don't want to use the `satellite` type, you want the `hybrid` type.